# Authenticating to Magento Rest API via Curl and token-based authentication fails

Tags: api, magento, curl

As all I want to do is connect to my own site, I should be able to ignore oAuth and do token-baseed authentication as per:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html

My curl request looks exactly like:

```
curl -X POST "https://magento.host/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token" \
     -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
     -d '{"username":"test@example.com", "password":"123123q"}'
```

The response I get is a HTML page from my own site that basically says `'page not found'` I'm obviously going to the correct domain, but it seems something else in the URL is incorrect. Any ideas?

Am I using the wrong URL?

Comment: Are you using Magento 2.0? This is a documentation for v2

Comment: Good question. How can I tell?

Comment: Apparently I'm not as using version 1.9.0. Thanks for clarifying. Just wondering if there is any similar way using version 1 where I'm not required to use oAuth.

Answer (score -1):

In version 1.9 you need to create a Guest endpoint. Then you don't need to use oAuth. You can see how to use it here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html

Comment: Thanks. Guest only has access to public resources whereas I need it for things like customers and orders.

Answer (score -1):

An authentication system that uses REST so that you do not need to actually track or manage the users in your system. This is done by using the HTTP methods POST, GET, PUT, DELETE. We take these 4 methods and think of them in terms of database interaction as CREATE, READ, UPDATE, DELETE.

There is no direct way to use REST token based authentication on the Magento 1.x version. You need to write this functionality to you for your own. I have write this functionality by using REST API and you can also follow this article for more details.

https://www.ipragmatech.com/magento-token-base-rest-api-for-authentication-and-authorization